# The receiver is not receiving broadcast in android studio

Tags: java, android, broadcast

The receiver is not receiving the broadcast from the sender. I just created a button and on that button i created an on click event. When This event is called the Sender will send broadcast to all apps in android phone.
[.xml file of Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd5eO.png)

The code used in used in main MainActivity to send Broadcast is;

```
package com.example.mk141.sendbroadcast;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void send_broadcast(View view)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent();
        i.setAction("com.example.mk141.sendbroadcast");
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        sendBroadcast(i);
    }
}
```

The Code used in Receiver to display a Toast on receiving the broadcasts is;

```
package com.example.mk141.recievebroadcast;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public MyReceiver()
    {
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context,"The Broadcast has been 
        recieved!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I also Changed the code in Android Manifest so that Receiver only receives broadcast against a specific action;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mk141.recievebroadcast">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.example.mk141.sendbroadcast">
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But when i run both sender and receiver then no Toast text is shown on pushing SEND BROADCAST button. Please anyone help me in solving this issue thanks!

Comment: I cant see where you actually called that send_broadcast message.

Comment: Sir sentBroadcast(i) is called in send_broadcast() event in MainActivity Class and Toast.makeText().show() is called in MyReciever Class .

Comment: "Sir sentBroadcast(i) is called in send_broadcast()" yes when actually you calling that "send_broadcast()" method. I can't find that.

Comment: Its an event for a button. When button is pressed that event will be called. Please see the picture attached.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd5eO.png